# C# console application code doesn't execute after await

Tags: c#, async-await, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to make a webscraper where I get all the download links for the css/js/images from a html file.

**Problem**

The first breakpoint does hit, but the second one not after hitting "Continue".

[Picture in Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jGcS.png)

Code I'm talking about:

```
  private static async void GetHtml(string url, string downloadDir)
    {

        //Get html data, create and load htmldocument 
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

        //This code gets executed
        var html = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);

        //This code not
        Console.ReadLine();
        var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);

        //Get all css download urls
        var linkUrl = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("link")
            .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("type", "")
            .Equals("text/css"))
            .Select(node=>node.GetAttributeValue("href",""))
            .ToList();

        //Downloading css, js, images and source code
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            for (var i = 0; i <scriptUrl.Count; i++)
            {

                    Uri uri = new Uri(scriptUrl[i]);
                    client.DownloadFile(uri,
                    downloadDir + @"\js\" + uri.Segments.Last());

            }
        }
```

**Edit**

Im calling the getHtml method from here:

```
    private static void Start()
    {
        //Create a list that will hold the names of all the subpages
        List<string> subpagesList = new List<string>();

        //Ask user for url and asign that to var url, also add the url to the url list
        Console.WriteLine("Geef url van de website:");
        string url = "https://www.hethwc.nl";


        //Ask user for download directory and assign that to var downloadDir
        Console.WriteLine("Geef locatie voor download:");
        var downloadDir = @"C:\Users\Daniel\Google Drive\Almere\C# II\Download tests\hethwc\";

        //Download and save the index file
        var htmlSource = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(url);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Daniel\Google Drive\Almere\C# II\Download tests\hethwc\index.html", htmlSource);

        // Creating directories 
        string jsDirectory = System.IO.Path.Combine(downloadDir, "js");
        string cssDirectory = System.IO.Path.Combine(downloadDir, "css");
        string imagesDirectory = System.IO.Path.Combine(downloadDir, "images");

        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(jsDirectory);
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(cssDirectory);
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(imagesDirectory);

        GetHtml("https://www.hethwc.nu", downloadDir);
    }
```

Comment: `async void` is a *famously* bad idea.  Your method isn't awaitable.  Use `async Task` instead and make sure to await your method when you call it.

Comment: Are you calling this from a sync main?

Answer (score 5):

How are you calling `GetHtml`? Presumably that is from a sync `Main` method, and you don't have any other non-worker thread in play (because your main thread exited): the process will terminate. Something like:

```
static void Main() {
    GetHtml();
}
```

The above will terminate the process immediately after `GetHtml` returns and the `Main` method ends, which will be at the first incomplete `await` point.

In current C# versions (C# 7.1 onwards) you can create an `async Task Main()` method, which will allow you to `await` your `GetHtml` method properly, as long as you change `GetHtml` to return `Task`:

```
async static Task Main() {
    await GetHtml();
}
```

Comment: If you're using C#7.0 or before, you can make `GetHtml` an `async Task` and leave `Main` as-is and simply call `GetHtml().Wait();` to wait for `GetHtml` to complete.

Comment: @MicahSwitzer I still feel horribly dirty calling `.Wait()` :)

Comment: Same, but it should be just fine for his purposes in a simple console app.